# Firestore query to check if an id is in a collection and then going to the subcollection in a single query

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore with 2 root collections, `properties` and `users`. Each of these properties has a list of "huurders" which are just userId's, and a subcollection of rooms each of which also has a "huurder" field which contains a UserId.

I'm trying to get a list of all rooms where the "y" field is equal to a given id. Right now I'm just checking if "y" contains the UserId i'm looking for, but I'm struggling about how to go into the subcollection x afterwards.

This is my function

```
override fun get(userId: String): Flow<RoomsResponse> = callbackFlow {
    val snapshotListener = dbRef.collection("properties").whereArrayContains("", ).addSnapshotListener() { snapshot, e ->
        val roomsResponse = if (snapshot != null) {
            val rooms = snapshot.toObjects(Room::class.java)
            Response.Success(rooms)
        } else {
            Response.Failure(e)
        }
        trySend(
    awaitClose { snapshotListener.remove()
}
}
```

This is incorrect given this would just return me a list of properties where the is in the array . I need to go one layer deeper and get the rooms. My firestore will be linked as an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore queries always returns the documents that you query on. They can't return documents from nested collection, or otherwise linked data.

So if you want to get a list rooms from the database, you'll need to query the `rooms` subcollection. To query across all collections named `rooms`, you can [use a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). And since you seem to have a `huurder` field in each `rooms` document, you should be able to get the correct results with:

```
dbRef.collectionGroup("rooms").whereEqualTo("huurder", userId)
```

This will give you a list of `rooms` document snapshots.

---

If you then want to find the property of a specific [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot) in these results, you can [get its `DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getDocumentReference(java.lang.String)) and then check the [parent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference#getParent()) of its [parent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#getParent()).